Does anyone understand the goal of the recent spate of spam on Super User?
In recent days, Super User has been hit by a large amount of spam.  Normally, spam has one of three primary purposes:

to steal
to sell a crappy product/service
to infect the recipient with malware
as a method of phishing

But this spam doesn't seem to conform to one or more of those agendas.  It's literally just a bunch of nonsense, often with a service number to call for some obscure issue that no one here is likely facing.  We flag and delete the spam so fast that almost no one sees it.  And it's so obviously spam that no one coming to this site will be fooled by it.
A possible agenda I can think of is to get those scam phone numbers high in the ranking of search engines that overvalue data (including incorrect/irrelevant data) from Stack Exchange sites, such as Google.  Similarly, some AI sites overvalue data from Stack Exchange sites.  To do that, a GoogleBot would have to see the spam at just the right moment, save the spam to its database, improperly identify the spam as real content, and then later feed the spam to unsuspecting Google users.  Seems unlikely, but possible, so maybe that's their goal.
Does anyone have a more likely explanation or understanding of the goal of this recent spate of spam on Super User?

They really want people to take out loans with them I guess.

I'd assume naive SEO stuffing - with more concern of quantity over quality.
It's also on some sites, essentially DDOSing charcoal, and smoke detector, and I've noticed that the spammers have been trying different patterns to try to get around the spam filters. The sheer volume is an attempt to get something through. In theory, a big enough wave can overwhelm user abilities to flag it. There's hundreds of these posts a day, and if we don't have enough active spam flaggers and mods, we can't manage to handle it.
That said... I've literally had a spammer flag me with what was the same contents as their comment spam so... I've no real clue to what they hope to achieve.

Thanks.  BTW, I've noticed the SE limitation of submitting only 1 flag every 5 seconds gets in the way of flagging it.  Maybe that limit could be changed to 1 flag every 3 seconds for Super User?  Or maybe no time period for those with over x rep points?

Funny thing is I'm hitting rate limits on destroying spammers. I'd be inclined to ask for adjusting or removing rate limits of flags as an emergency measure on he appropriate site :D

LOL... I didn't know the destroy function had a rate limit.  I don't think I've ever had to destroy more than 2 or 3 accounts in an hour... That rate limit seems counterproductive for what you are dealing with.

I mean, not hitting it is a good thing.  But yeah, I do feel like its an attempt to DDOS the spam mitigation systems. Its not going to work, of course, but as they say, an attempt was made ;)

Just posted: https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/405300/spam-influx-time-to-reduce-or-remove-spam-flag-rate-limiting-for-community-memb

Also I'm a little annoyed its noticeable. charcoal and the community has been brilliant in dealing with it so far. I might even take these spammers a little personally :D

This is entirely a series of guesses:
SU/SE are sites with a high reputation. Content on these sites is ranked pretty highly on search engines, their bots, the various crawlers and spiders that canvas and catalog the web, and particularly in these days of the more complex bots commonly called "AI" that are desperately looking for good data to feed their garbage maws. This means that these sites are juicy targets and any spam/scam post that gets to stay here any real length of time could be quite profitable.
I would guess that this current wave may represent a collection of new spam organizations, or the development of some new script or bot being used by spamming groups running out of under-developed places around the globe. The content feels less like bot-created nonsense though, much of it beginning with posts that seem to be created manually before being edited over into the spam posts, and so I've just assumed from near the beginning of this wave that some new groups are trying to set up shop.

Its been going on for over a year. The big apparent difference is they seem to be more active, and the spam comes in big waves rather than a sneaky trickle
